# JavaScript element background color not changing on the web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change the background color of an `<li>` element but its not working. I'm not getting an error just that the color doesn't change on web page. I have tried multiple approaches such as assigning the element a class name and having that classname in CSS and also `linesin[0].style.backgroundColor = "white"` but non is working.
below is my JS code:

```
var vals;
var rows;
var sum;
var rowsarr = [];
var avg;
var lines;
var linesin = [];
    function obser1() {
        const trades = document.querySelector('.scrollbar-dark');
        const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
                    vals = [...mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelectorAll("span")].map(span => span.textContent);
                    lines = [...mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelectorAll("li")];
                    if (vals.length == 4) {
                        rows = vals[2];
                        rowsarr.push(rows);
                    }
                    if (vals.length == 3) {
                        rows = vals[1];
                        rowsarr.push(rows);
                    }
                    linesin.push(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
                    console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
                    console.log(rows + "  rows");
                }
            })
            function arraysum(x, y) {
                return parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);
            }
            sum = rowsarr.reduce(arraysum);
            console.log(rowsarr.length + "  length");
            
            if (rowsarr.length >= 100 && rowsarr.length<115) {
                avg = sum / 50;
                console.log("average is  " + avg);
            }
            /*This is the problem*/
            if (rows > avg) {
                console.log(rows + "  large" + "  average  " + avg);
                console.log(linesin[0]);
                linesin[0].className = "large";
            }
        });
        observer.observe(trades, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
            attributes: true,
            characterData: true
        })
```

and below is my CSS:

```
.large{
    background-color:whitesmoke !important;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you create a fiddle because I am able to apply it? 
Did you tried RGB pattern?

Comment: The reason why people can't help is because you are not sharing all the code. If you share your HTML we might be able to help. We are on the blind here...

Comment: @gass I understand your point but I'm writing a chrome extension to manipulate a crypto exchange i cant share the whole page here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use addClass method

```
linesin[0].querySelector('li').addClass('large');
```

Comment: Thank you. i cant try the code becuase the website has changed most of its html structure and elements and my code is not working anymore, sadly. 
Thank you for your answer...